# How to retrieve client and server IP address and port number in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to search a lot to find a way to know the client and server ip address and port number. So far I found:

1. **Client ip** : can be known by `req.ip`.
2. **Client port** : I searched a lot but I couldn't find any way to find this client ephemeral port. After inspecting the `req` and `res` objects, I found that sometimes `res.connection._peername` contains the client ip address and port number. But this is not the reliable way to find the port number because in some request this property is missing. So, what is the correct way to know about the port ?
3. **Server ip** : Here I am interested in knowing the external or public ip for the server. I searched a bit for the same and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273128/how-to-get-my-external-ip-address-with-node-js) which uses some external api to retrieve the external ip. Is it the only possible way to find the external IP ? Or are there any other way possible ?
4. **Server port** : It can be known with `listener.address().port` [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546173/nodejs-get-ip-used-by-remoteaddress) . But can it be known from `req` or `res` objects ? Actually I want to know the port number from within the middleware where I have `req`,`res` and `next`only( basically `app.use(function(req,res,next){...}))`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get those four values with these properties if you have a direct connection with the client (no proxies in the way):

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
req.connection.remotePort
req.connection.localAddress
req.connection.localPort
```

Relevant node.js source code pointer in net.js: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/863952ebadd4909a66bb9da7868bf75bbbe1462d/lib/net.js#L608

Note: While you  access these as property values, they are technically implemented as getters.  You cannot set these properties.

---

If there is server infrastructure such as load balancers, proxies, etc... in front of your actual server, the above local values may return the local server, not what the actual public IP/port that the client originally connected to.  The only way to retrieve the original public IP/port would be if your infrastructure sets the originals as a HTTP headers (which some proxies set IP, don't know if any proxies set port) since they are not present in the current raw TCP connection from the proxy.

For cases where a proxy is involved, you may also want to look at some HTTP headers:

```
X-Forwarded-For - The IP address of the client before it went through the proxy
X-Forwarded-Port - The port of the client before it went through the proxy
```

The X-Forwarded headers may also be a comma separated list if it has gone through multiple proxies such as:

```
X-Forwarded-For: OriginatingClientIPAddress, proxy1-IPAddress, proxy2-IPAddress
```

There is also a standard header as of [RFC 7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) 2014:

```
Forwarded: for=192.0.2.60; proto=http; by=203.0.113.43
```

Comment: `req.ip` is what Express uses for its internal trust proxy handling.  Better to use that than `req.connection.remoteAddress` if Express is being used.  For the port though, the upstream proxy doesn't usually send that information.

Comment: @Brad - I could not find supporting code for `req.ip` so I was not as willing to trust it as to trust the values I found the actual code for.  `req.connection` is the `Socket` object for your http request and these four properties are properties of any TCP connection in node.js.  Express may do something in addition, but these come straight from the underlying socket implementation.  Yes, proxies may obscure info about the remote connection - my answer mentions that.

Comment: Right, I was responding to your comment about upstream proxies.  You can read about the trust proxy settings here:  http://expressjs.com/en/api.html  Your suggestion just gets the immediate connection, which is often desired.  However, if you want to know what the request IP actually is and you have a proxy in front, it's easiest just to rely on Express' built-in handling of this situation.

Comment: `req.connection.localAddress` will give the local IP address of the server. Is it possible to retrieve the public IP address of the server in a similar manner ?

Comment: @user2805872 - `req.connection.loadAddress` should be the server-side IP address of the TCP connection.  If there is no proxy in between you and the public internet, then that should be your public IP address.  If there is a proxy, then that address will not be the public IP address because the public IP address does not actually belong to your server.  I added more info about proxy headers to my answer, though I don't know if it will get you the true public IP address that the client originally connected to.

Comment: Hi what if you are not using node.js, in plain vanilla js can you obtain remote (client) port? Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel - You can't do networking in plain JS.  It has to be running inside of some environment such as nodejs, browser, etc... to provide it networking.  So access to attributes of a TCP connection come from the environment that Javascript is running in.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey! Thanks for your reply this topic is over like 7 years ago?  Yes I understand this needs to go through browser. By plain JS I mean adding the JS code below the HTML. Say I have chrome connecting to a website, is there a way to 'sniff' or collect info about the remote port? I have access to the backend server actually which is Django but getting the remote port number on that end is pure luck. It looks through the socket and `getpeername` but sometimes the remote port field is not there... So I look at client side...

Comment: @Gabriel - I am not aware of any way to get IP address info from within the browser.